# Web server woes - only display home page on all sites

Tags: apache2, configuration

I'm running Ubuntu server 15 and am migrating all my websites, a combo of Wordpress and drupal sites to the new server - from Ubuntu server 14. It's all working fine BUT I can only view the URLs eg. www.mysite.com NOT any sub pages eg. www.mysite.com/abc/123.html. Looks like a rewrite module issue. It's loaded rewrite.load so not sure why not working.

I'm sure it just a still error in my apache2.conf file, old server was 2.4.7 vs 2.4.10 so config files of both should be similar.

On the drupal side all the links of the site just point to home page, on WP site they show a 404 error.

I have all the .htaccess files copied over it seems but looks like they are not working ???

Thanks (the migration went well apart from the Mysql passwords that are now no longer stored in plain text)

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, the rewrite module was not loaded, I was looking at the old server! All is well and Note To Self, and others, the rewrite module is not enable by default on Apache / Ubuntu installs!!! :( :(